# Transversal Intersections - Some Examples

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

Here is a part of an exercise from Guillemin-Pollack:

> Which of the following linear subspaces intersect transversally?
>
> (d) $R^k\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \times R^l$ in $R^n$. (Depends on
>   $k,l,n$.)
>
> (e) $R^k\times \{0\}$ and $ R^l\times \{0\}$ in $R^n$. (Depends on
>   $k,l,n$.)
>
> (f) $V\times \{0\}$ and the diagonal $\Delta$ in $V\times V$.

What's the conceptual difference between (d) and (e)? It seems to me that the answer in both cases is the same, namely the intersection is transversal iff $k+l\ge n$. Just because two subspaces intersect transversally iff the sum of their dimensions is greater than or equal to the dimension of the ambient space. Is that correct?

For (f), suppose $\dim V=n$. Then $\dim (V\times \{0\})=n; \dim \Delta=n; \dim (V\times V)=2n$. Since $\dim (V\times \{0\})+\dim \Delta=\dim (V\times V)$, the intersection is transversal. Is that correct?

Comment: "Just because two subspaces intersect transversally iff the sum of their dimensions is greater than or equal to the dimension of the ambient space". That is only guaranteed to be true if the intersection of the spaces is trivial. Transversality is related to $V+W$, not $\dim V+\dim W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is crucial, when you write $$\mathbb{R}^k\times \{0\}\qquad\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n$$
you really mean $$\{(x_1,\ldots,x_k,0,\ldots, 0)\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$
whereas $$\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}^k\qquad\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n$$
means $$\{(0,\ldots, 0, x_{n-k+1},\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$
Therefore in case (e), there is always one subspace that contains the other. It is therefore much more difficult to be in transverse position, the bigger one has to be the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now. What about (f)? As pointed out in the comments, my approach is incorrect, but I don't see how to prove it then. Basically, as far as I understand, I need to show that given any $(v_0,w_0)\in V\times V$ there is $(v,v)\in \Delta$ and $(u,0)\in V\times \{0\}$ such that $(v_0,w_0)=(u,0)+(v,v)$. But I can't see why this holds.

Comment: @user500094 Take $(w_0,w_0) \in \Delta$ and $(v_0-w_0,0) \in V \times \{0\}$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Oh, it's that simple... Thank you.