# Do these linear spaces intersect transversally?

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-topology, transversality

> Do these linear spaces intersect transversally? (For a,b, find a relationship between $n,l$ and $k$ that do so.
>
> a. $\mathbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times \mathbb{R^l} $ in $\mathbb{R^n}$
>
> b. $\mathbb{R^k}\times \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R^l}\times \{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$
>
> c. $V\times \{0\}$ and diagonal in $V\times V$

My Try:

What I know is two subspaces $V,W$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ intersect tranversally means $V+W=\mathbb{R^n}$. So for part a, is $n=k+l$ would do that? But I have no idea about part b,c. Please help.

Comment: (a) $n\leq k+l$, with $k,l<n$.

Comment: @jfKeys: Why it should be an inequality? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: (b) They will never generate the whole space since they can only get the zero of the last factor. So, no solutions.  (c) If $n$ is even and $V=\mathbb{R}^{n/2}$.

Comment: Because it is fine. They only need to generate the whole space. Take the case $k=l=n-1$. Then $k+l=2n-2$, which could be $\geq n$. The condition $k,l < n$ is just such that they are actually subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transversal Intersections - Some Examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649715/transversal-intersections-some-examples)

Comment: @jfKeys: Got it, thanks.

Comment: @jfKeys what about the case $k=n$ or $l=n$ in (b)? In either of these cases, $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^k \times \{0\} + \{0\} \times \mathbb R^l$. (I interpret $\mathbb R^n\times \{0\}$ as $\mathbb R^n$.) For (c), why does one need $n$ even and what does $R^\frac{n}{2}$ have to do with $V$?

Comment: @ user500094: We cannot have the cases where $k=n$ or $n=l$ because at least the last coordinate should be a zero in both spaces.

Comment: There was a typo in part c. I corrected it. Sorry.

Comment: @Convex okay, thanks, then my interpretation of $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ was incorrect since there is no such subspace. For (c), see the comments (to the answer) in the question cited above.

Comment: While it is true that one could think of $\mathbb{R}^n\times \{0\}$ as the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$, strictly speaking their elements are of different nature. It is fine to assume it, but the assumption should be clarified explicitly. There is another problem, which is even more awkward. $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^n$, in order to be considered both as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ they use different isomorphisms on the tuples. The first drops the last element, while the second has to drop the first element.

Comment: @user500094 In (c) I just noticed that I completely ignored the word diagonal in the question. So, for (c) the answer should be always, since every element $(x,y)$ can be written as $(x,y)=(x-y,0)+(y,y)$

Comment: @jfKeys Sorry, the word "diagonal" was indeed missing in the question; I didn't pay attention to it and I mistakenly thought your previous answer concerns the diagonal.

Comment: @All: Missing the word "diagonal" was a typo which was my mistake. Im sorry.